# Count of distinct items mongodb

Tags: mongodb, distinct

Given the following document structure in MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f00f745b4124b8b6b6f143"), "item" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f00f8a5b4124b8b6b6f144"), "item" : "b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f00f935b4124b8b6b6f145"), "item" : "A" }
```

I'm trying to find the `distinct` items **and** the count of those items.  Running

```
db.test.distinct('item')
```

results in `[ "A", "b" ]`.  How can I output the `count` of each dinstinct item?  Example output would be `[ ["A",2] , ["b",1] ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#calculate-count-sum-and-average). Group by "item" then do a count:

```
db.test.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$item", count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```